# Check existence of two elements using Python, Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check the existence of two elements(A,B) on a website.What I need is to click on the element A if it exists if not go ahead and look for B and click on it if it exists. Below is part of my sample code.

```
try:
        abc= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#rso > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > h3 > a")))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
    except TimeoutException:
        continue
    else:
        element.click()


try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#rso > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > h3 > a")))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
    except TimeoutException:
        continue
    else:
        abc.click()
        time.sleep(randint(1, 15))


print('Process completed successfully')
```

The issue that I face is that the code only looks for the first element and doesn't go ahead into the next try. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below to click first element and in case it's not found - click second:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "first.element"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "second.element"))).click()
```

P.S. Replace `"first.element"`, `"second.element"` with real CSS selectors

If both elements might not be present on page:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "first.element"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "second.element"))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Both elements not found")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Andersson :)

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
try:
    elements = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'first.element'
                              'second.element')
        )
    )
    if elements[0].tag_name == 'first.element':
        print("login fail")
    elif elements[0].tag_name == 'second.element':
        print("login")
except:
    print("Both elements not found")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).